# Maven 1.x Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-1

I've got the challenge to maintain a project setup using Maven 1.1. It's some kind of a legacy project, so updating is not an option, at least not currently :-/

So my question is: how do I enable my Eclipse to work with Maven 1? IIRC there were at least 2 Plugins available in the early ages of Maven projects. As far as I can see, the up-to-date plugins are unable to process such ancient projects, are they?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try with m2e?

Comment: Maven 1 is no longer supported: http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/  I know you've stated that updating is not an option but..... Perhaps it's the only sane choice. I do apologize for this posting, but sometimes a project accumulates too much technical debt... Maven 1 was such a poor build tool it was completely re-written. Maven 2 and 3 work quite differently.

Comment: If you cannot update Maven you could try to downgrade eclipse until you find suitable plugins. But this means also using unsupported software. So you have to decide if it is worth it or if updating is the less painful option.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I'll try migrating to maven3 later. I know I will run into troubles - there are some custom plugins, and I have no idea what's going on inside, yet. But migrating is necessary, it's only the wrong moment, as often :-)